# Get user input on their exact location

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, geolocation

I have built a PHP website that helps its users to organize their events.

An important part of the system is defining the event location, which will usually be the home location for the person creating the event.

I am trying to create a way to allow a user to add 'places' to their profile by selecting those places on some sort of a map, or maybe take a textual string and show it on a map (how do I avoid people misspells?).

Also important, the service should allow addresses from all over the world.

Has anyone ever done something like this or has any solution?

Comment: Downvoted because this isn't asking a question that can be helpfully answered. Refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you just need to integrate with a mapping service, such as [Google Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html) or [Bing Maps](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/web.aspx).

You'd locally keep a database of the "places" created by users and display them as overlays on the maps.  Addresses and lat/long coordinates are both usable, and generally interchangeable through the API.  (And the search provided by each handles spelling mistakes pretty well.)

Comment: Going through the code samples, it looks really amazing.
The only thing I couldn't find (I have yet to go through the whole user guide of course) is the option to have a detailed map (with streets and house numbers - not streetview though) that allows a user to pinpoint a place in it. Is that possible using Google Maps API?

Comment: @JohnB: With house numbers overlaid on the map itself?  I've never seen them do that, no.  One can search for an address easily enough, but I don't think there's a way to just show _all_ of them.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Google's Maps API](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html)? It's actuall pretty easy to interact with it. YOu should find something in the [Examples](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/index.html).

You could store the locations inside your database and when the user opens the map, load his locations onto the map. Google also has a (Reverse-) [GeoCoding](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests) service. There are some alternatives available that you do not need to rely on Google like building your own GeoService with the help of free data (like OpenStreetMap). This takes lots of ressources so for the start of the project, I think Google is just fine.